# Slide modal from top on JS command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

Starting point for my question, [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/pLDwe)

I have been looking for a way to get a slide on page that would be triggered by a JS call. Looking around, the pen above seems to be what I am looking for, but instead of a JS function, the animation is triggered by a checkbox.

One of my options would be to make the button invisible and trigger the checking using jQuery like this

```
$("#toggle")[0].checked = !($("#toggle")[0].checked)
```

While this line works, I am trying to find here a more JS/jQuery animation solution, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option of hide check and trigger the checkbox will work ... other thing you can do is add -- remove a classname but you need to change the CSS.

If you want just simple Jquery you can use `slideUp / Down` ...

```js
$('.container').click(function(){
  $('.message').slideToggle(500)
})
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container {
  padding:50px;
}
h1 {
  font-size:40px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#191919;
}

h2 {
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#888;
  padding:5px 0;
}

.message {
background:#181818;
color:#FFF;
height: 150px;
padding: 20px;
  display:none;
}

.message h1 {
  color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message">
  <h1> hello, I'm a hidden message. You found it.</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Jquery Slide Down Toggle Demo</h1>
  <h2> Click here to Toggle the hidden mesage.</h2>
</div>
```